# How to perform a search on selected fields in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have `User` schema with three fields, a `username`, `email`, and `password`, how would I do a query with mongoose in which I search the `username` and `email` fields only and return matched documents.

For example in expressjs the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/search?q=testuser
```

Posting to that ur should return an array of documents that have `testuser` either in its email, username, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is as simple as pass the values into `find()` method with an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition.

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IkVW9dTSr76) example:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "username": {
        "$regex": "testuser"
      }
    },
    {
      "email": {
        "$regex": "testuser"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Return the values where `username` or `email` contains `testuser`.

With `mongoose` you can use the saeme:

```js
yourModel.find({
            "$or": [
               { "username": { "$regex":"testuser" } },
               {"email": { "$regex":"testuser" } }
             ]
        }).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        })
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it so that there is just one search parameter that contains one value for example ```testuser``` and then it searches through the two fields and returns matching documents.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Can you add an example in your post with the expected input?

Comment: Thank you for modifying your answer, but one more thing, the word, ```testuser``` can also be a part of the field, not just the field itself, for example, if the users name is ```testuser user```, that model would also get returned, perhaps this can be done with regex.

Comment: Yes, with `regex` is possible. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great, so does that mean that the keyword ```testuser``` can be any part of the field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227710/discussion-between-svoruganti-and-j-f).

Comment: One more thing, how would you make it match case insensitive instead of case sensitive?

Comment: You can use `$options: "i"`. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fwh-T9P5W1B) example.